# build and design Crystal Report in ASP.net with more than one table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, crystal-reports, dataset

I want to build and design Report using Crystal Report using ASP.net.
The big challenge for me is how to store more than one table in dataset.
this is the structure for a dataset:

[click to see dataset structure](http://postimage.org/image/62zpk9egt/)

i want to know how to build a report for a specific Employee ( by ID ) and add all employee information ( from employee table) and all related information that come from other two tables
((from AppraisalForm table by FK: ID_employee) and from internalChallenges table by FK: emp_id and FK: form_id))

and but all this data in one dataset and make this dataset as source for my crytal repor.